# How to modify CRUD screen as popup/modals using Jhipster 6.8?

Tags: jhipster, angular9

I am using Jhipster latest version 6.8 and angular 9 for creating CRUD entities. By default, Create screen, Edit screen, View Screen opens as separate screen rather than in a popup. I want to make single page application so that Edit/View/Create opens as a modal over search screen.

Comment: Modals were removed in JHipster 5.0, so you  could have a look at latest 4.x sample app: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/tree/v4.14.1/src/main/webapp/app/entities/operation